# While adding cells of a column in excel, exclude some cells based on text values in another column

Tags: excel

I'm working on a commissions report for work, and I want to set a formula for my upcoming commission payment.

My report is ongoing, so it includes already paid commissions from previous months. I have a column for "Commission Amount" and a "Paid?" column for if the commission has been paid or not (In this, I put text value "YES" or "NO" depending on if it has been paid or not). I also have an "Upcoming Commission Payment" cell that I'd like to set to add up my unpaid commissions.

So, I'd like the result in that cell to be the sum of all "Commission Amount" cells whose corresponding "Paid?" column reads "NO". How can I exclude any that read "YES" without having to reselect the range every time?

Comment: Use *SUMIFS()* or *SUMPRODUCT()*

Comment: What does this have to do with conditional formatting?

Comment: Sorry, that should've been formulas. I'm still learning quite a bit about this.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B10)*(C2:C10="NO"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I realize this is a beginner question. I'm still trying to get things figured out, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @BrendanC.That is Okay............I am only a Student myself.............